# Ajax ReorderList FindControl Problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am using an Ajax ReorderList in my content page and I would like to get the value of text box or a label in code behind(C#).

However I always receive a null value,

any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution:

for example to reach a textbox inside InsertItemTemplate

TextBox uploadedfile = (TextBox)reorderList1.FindControl("_rliInsert").FindControl("txtName");

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to do it - `(TextBox) e.Item.Cells[1].Controls[0];`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        private Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string id)
        {
            return root.ID == id
                       ? root
                       : (root.Controls.Cast<Control>()
                             .Select(c => FindControlRecursive(c, id)))
                             .FirstOrDefault(t => t != null);
        }
```